# javascript reduce to convert a flat array to a nested array using reduce/map functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, reduce

I have the following array (mySQL results set):

```
    [
        {"eventId":"84","shootId":"72","clubEventId":"253","clubId":"7"},
        {"eventId":"84","shootId":"72","clubEventId":"254","clubId":"5"},
        {"eventId":"84","shootId":"72","clubEventId":"255","clubId":"6"},
        {"eventId":"85","shootId":"72","clubEventId":"256","clubId":"7"},
        {"eventId":"85","shootId":"72","clubEventId":"257","clubId":"5"},
        {"eventId":"85","shootId":"72","clubEventId":"258","clubId":"6"}
   ]
```

I would like to elegantly transform this with a reduce function to have the following structure:

```
{
  "84" : {
    "clubEvents" : {
      "253" : {
        "clubEventId" : 253,
        "clubId" : 7 },
      "254" : {
        "clubEventId" : 254,
        "clubId" : 5 },
      "255" : {
        "clubEventId" : 255,
        "clubId" : 6}
    },
   
    "shootId" : 72,
   
  },
  "85" : {
     "clubEvents" : {
      "253" : {
        "clubEventId" : 256,
        "clubId" : 7 },
      "254" : {
        "clubEventId" : 257,
        "clubId" : 5 },
      "255" : {
        "clubEventId" : 258,
        "clubId" : 6}
    },
    "shootId" : 72,
   }
}
```

I would be most grateful for any assistance.

Comment: What did you try? And how do the clubEvents properties relate to the clubEventId since the don't seem to be the same in the 85 event.

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the two levels of nesting for assignments.

```js
const
    data = [{ eventId: "84", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "253", clubId: "7" }, { eventId: "84", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "254", clubId: "5" }, { eventId: "84", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "255", clubId: "6" }, { eventId: "85", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "256", clubId: "7" }, { eventId: "85", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "257", clubId: "5" }, { eventId: "85", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "258", clubId: "6" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { eventId, shootId, clubEventId, clubId }) => {
        r[eventId] ??= { clubEvents: {}, shootId };
        r[eventId].clubEvents[clubEventId] = { clubEventId, clubId };
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  { eventId: "84", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "253", clubId: "7" },
  { eventId: "84", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "254", clubId: "5" },
  { eventId: "84", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "255", clubId: "6" },
  { eventId: "85", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "256", clubId: "7" },
  { eventId: "85", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "257", clubId: "5" },
  { eventId: "85", shootId: "72", clubEventId: "258", clubId: "6" },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { eventId, shootId, clubEventId, clubId } = curr;
  if (!acc[eventId]) {
    acc[eventId] = {
      clubEvents: {
        [clubEventId]: { clubEventId, clubId },
      },
      shootId,
    };
  } else {
    const obj = acc[eventId];
    obj["clubEvents"][clubEventId] = { clubEventId, clubId };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```